# How to run code when coming back to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

in my application I have 3 activities. First one -the main from which I start activity #2. From  #2 I start #3 and at the same time I finish #2. When I finish #3 I automatically come back to #1. Question: How can I add/run code when coming back from 3 to 1?

not sure if it makes sense. But what I want to do is, when ending #3 and coming back to #1 I want to check if file xyz exists and based on it to change UI in activity #1.

OnResume in #1 is not ran, never. (Probably system doesn't run onpause for this first activity)

If there was only activity #1 and 2 I could use startActivityForResult. But two activities don't do what I need...

Comment: If you post some of your code it would be easier to understand but there are different ways you could do it. You could create a method in activity #1 and call that from #3. Or put it in the onCreate() to call depending on certain criteria

Comment: how can I call method created in #1 from #3? Putting code in onCreate does not help me..

Comment: @codeMagic - That doesn't really work well. There's no good way for activity #3 to get a reference to the instance of activity #1 that's actually running.

Comment: thank you. I'll try this. This looks to me as a best solution. To call method when finishing #3.

Comment: trying your suggestion. found out that need to use static method. But then I get error for findViewById

'Button mainI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_main)'

I want to make button b_main inactive in layout #1

Comment: @codeMagic : NEVER suggest accessing fields or methods of an `Activity` from outside of that `Activiry` itself. That is not how the `Activity` class is meant to work.

Comment: @Radiak : I don't understand that you say `onResume()` is never called when returning to `Activity` #1. In my experience, an `Activity` is paused immediately when it is hidden by another `Activity` (either partially or completely).

Comment: I've put some code (just Log.d for testing) in onResume in activity#1. When I come back from #3 (sometimes even after few minutes) code in onresume is never called

Comment: use onrestart instead of onresume....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See below example.

your activity#1 code is like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onRestart();

          //Do your code here
}
}
```

Your activity#3 code is like this

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity3); 
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}


}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I want to change UI (disable/enable) button(s) from MainActivity layout. If I want to use your approach need to use static method. But then I get error for findViewById 'Button mainI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_main)'

Comment: you should try this in activity#3 on backPress() finish() that activity and in activity#1 onRestart() put your code. I already update code see that.

Comment: thank you Arvind. I had had wrong OnRestart statement. Now it works well

Comment: In my case OnRestart() app didn't do anything so I put code inside OnResume and than worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

From activity #1, don't start activity #2. Instead, start activity #3, passing a flag in the intent to tell activity #3 to start activity #2. If activity #3 calls `startActivity` from inside `onCreate`, there will be no screen flicker. That way, activity #1 can use `startActivityForResult` and get the result back from activity #3.

It's a bit of a kludge, but it works nicely.

Comment: really interesting idea, will think about it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aspects to consider:

1. Why is in #1 onPause()/onResume() not called? Are you sure about this? It's very unlikely.
   The Android documentation says about [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29):

   > (...) When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will
   >   be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, (...)
2. It seems to me that you should consider to look into using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) instead of multiple activities.
3. A quick-fix could be to call startActivity for #1 when finishing #3. You only have to make sure that the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for #1 is set to singleTop.

Comment: I've put some code (just Log.d for testing) in onResume in activity#1. When I come back from #3 (sometimes even after few minutes) code in onresume is never called

Comment: I don't know why but onrestart in activity #1 main, is not called when I come back from #3.

public void onRestart(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     Log.d(TAG, "onrestart runs in main.java");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Make a Method on Your Acivity 1:

```
public void changeViewsMethod(){
    textView.setText("demo");
}
```

Now On Your Activty 2 do this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    ((YOU_ACTIVITY1) getApplicationContext()).changeViewsMethod();
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a Preference Variable in OnPause of Activity #3 (something like Activity3Finished=true)
Now you can check in every Activity if Activity #3 has finished.

Dont forget to reset the Variable in OnCreate of #3.

Comment: yes, but I don't know where to put code that would check #3 state. And I don't need to have checker that checks state every single second/ minute. I think that it'd be easier to run code once I go back from #3 to #1.

Comment: what do you mean with state? You dont need to check every second, only set the flag when your condition is true

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'flag'. IMO I imagine it as single 'if condition' code that is put somewhere. Am I correct?

Comment: yeah, with flag i mean the Preference Variable that i mentioned in my Answer. Set that Var if Activty #3 is finished, if Activity #1 comes back to live you say if(var == true) { ..make something ..}

Comment: well, I think I know what you mean, but what I don't know is WHEN I should perform check (if(var == true) { ..make something ..} ). The problem is that I can't catch moment of coming back to #1. I've put testing code Log.d in onResume in #1, but it's never called..

Comment: the same for OnRestart, it's not called when coming back to #1